# <ice:outputMedia> and <ui:repeat>

Tags: icefaces

I am trying to play sequence of .wav files with the following code. My Problem is some times all files are playing at a time some times one after other. Simple to say xyz.wav files are playing randomly. Is there a way to thread.sleep or to wait till one file finishes playing the audio???
<

(ui:repeat value="#{captcha.imageSpeechFiles}" var="cart" rendered="#{captcha.play}">
 (ice:outputMedia source="#{cart}" mimeType="audio/x-wav" player="windows" style="width:0px;height:0px;" >
(param name="play" value="true"/>
(/ice:outputMedia>
(/ui:repeat>

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question. instead of ice:outputMedia tag if we use embed as shown below its working fine.

(ui:repeat value="#{popup.imageSpeechFiles}" var="cart" rendered="#{popup.play}">
 (embed id="embdwav" src="#{cart}" autostart="true" hidden="true"  />
(/ui:repeat>